# New Apple Map Transition

Tags: xcode, ios6

How can i do the new appleMaps transition in iOS 6, which allows you to take the map view and lift it to see and set the settings menu.
I would like to put this transition in my apps in xCode, does somebody know how to do that stuff?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

The new API for using maps in iOS6 is named "MapKit", here are the specifications :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html

Hope it helps you :)